# 2sxc Content Workflow integration sponsor query

Tags: 2sxc

Is there currently a sponsor to integrate content workflow approval before publishing of content within the 2sxc content module? Similar to the DNN EVOQ workflow/Mandeeps Live html editor (http://www.mandeeps.com/products/dnn-modules/live-html).

Client has specified this as a major requirement for a site I was intending on implementing with the 2sxc framework. Is there any integration that would allow such a workflow?

Thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on something in this area - not clear yet if it will work out, but if everything works, it should be out in about 2 months.

Comment: Hi Daniel, any update on whether this will be available (even in a beta capacity) in the coming weeks? Thx